# Connection to LocalDB using OleDBConnection

Tags: localdb

How to get it working in C# ?

I got it working from a client written in Delphi 7 using OleDBConnection which was fairly easy.
But I cannot get it working in visual studio 2012 C#

I need 2 ways of connecting,

the first one using an SQLConnection works partially using this connectionstring:

> Data
>   Source=(localdb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename="E:\SQLServerData\AdventureWorksLT2008_Data.mdf";Initial
>   Catalog=;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=

the second should use an oledb connection using this connectionstring:

> Provider=SQLNCLI11;Data
>   Source=(localdb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=\"E:\SQL Server
>   Data\AdventureWorksLT2008_Data.mdf\";Initial Catalog=;Integrated
>   Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=

This always fails with message:

> "An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file \"E:\SQL Server
>   Data\AdventureWorksLT2008_Data.mdf\" failed. A database with the same
>   name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on
>   UNC share."

Comment: I have removed "AttachDbFilename" part, it works fine. I found my database is attached somewhere else, could not make it work until i remive it.

Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; Initial Catalog=MyDatabaseName; Integrated Security=True

Comment: If you remove the "AttachDBFileName" part, than you are not using localDB but your database (mdf file) is attached in a sql server instance. That works, but that's not what I wanted. I have bypassed my problem by writing a dll in Delphi (apparantly works better with ado than vs 2013) and than use that dll in my c# application.